# Simple Linked List in C. Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c

I'm new to C and this language is confusing me a bit. 
I keep getting a segmentation fault 11 when running my quite simple linked list code:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *init(){
    struct node *l = NULL;
    return l;
}

struct node *newNode(int val){
    struct node* n = init();
    n = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->val = val;
    n->next=NULL;
    return n;
}

void append(struct node* h, int val){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = h;
    int i = 0;
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    printf("TestAppend");
    temp= newNode(val);
}

int main(){
    struct node* l = init();
    printf("Test1\n");
    append(l, 15);
    printf("Test2\n");
    struct node* temp = init();
    temp = l; 
}
```

can someone please explain why?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change init function to:

```
struct node *init()
{
    void* p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return (struct node*)p;    
}
```

Edit:
and free it at the end! – Woodrow Barlow

The segmentation fault is because your code is pointing to NULL.

Comment: and free it at the end!

Answer (score 0):

If you replace calls to `init()` with simple `NULL` (which is what it is), you will see for yourself that `append` tries to use `NULL->next`.

Answer (score 0):

In *append*, you should check for 'temp!=NULL' first to avoid the seg fault. Also you are declaring an unnecesary local variable which you are not using at all.